# how to fetch commented user name on posts in laravel

Tags: laravel, post, comments

SQLSTATE[42S22]:(SQL: select `name` from `users` inner join `postcomments` on `users`.`id` = `postcomments`.`user_id` and `postcomments`.`user_id` = user_id where `users`.`id` in (9))

**my users model**

```
    public function users()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');
    }

    public function commenteduser()
    {
      return $this->users()->join('postcomments', function($join){
      $join->on('users.id', '=', 'postcomments.user_id')
      ->where('postcomments.user_id' ,'=', 'user_id');
    })->select('name');
    }
```

**my post model**

```
    public function users()
    {
     return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');
    }

    public function commenteduser()
    {
   return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');
    }
```

i want not in (9))

i want users.id = 9

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question

Comment: add your table structure in question.

Comment: `$post->commenteduser()->whereKey(9)->first()->name`